# Finding an estimator for a binomial parameter using the method of moments

Tags: probability

A random variable subject to binomial distribution $B(100,p)$.Find estimator of $p$ using method of moment.The values $x :14,13,17,15,20,25,13,22$?

I got :

$$Ex=np=\frac{139}8$$
$$Vx=np (1-p)=\frac{\sum(x-Ex)^2}8=141.875/8$$

$$1-p=\frac{141.875}{139}$$

$$p=-0.021$$

It's negative so I think it's not correct. Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: please, show your work

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You know $np=\frac{139}8$ and $n=100$,so $p=\ldots $

Comment: So I do not need to find Vx? So p=0.17375?why we Do not find estimator of n?

Answer (score 1):

$n=100$ has been given to you in the question, there is only one unknown parameter $p$ and we can get an estimator from the first moment.

We can recover $\hat{p}$ by

$$100\hat{p} = \frac18 \sum_{i=1}^8 x_i$$